# Apache Flink read at least 2 record to trigger sink

Tags: apache-flink

I am write my Apache Flink(1.10) to update records real time like this:

```
public class WalletConsumeRealtimeHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        walletConsumeHandler();
    }

    public static void walletConsumeHandler() throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        FlinkUtil.initMQ();
        FlinkUtil.initEnv(env);
        DataStream<String> dataStreamSource = env.addSource(FlinkUtil.initDatasource("wallet.consume.report.realtime"));
        DataStream<ReportWalletConsumeRecord> consumeRecord =
                dataStreamSource.map(new MapFunction<String, ReportWalletConsumeRecord>() {
                    @Override
                    public ReportWalletConsumeRecord map(String value) throws Exception {
                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        ReportWalletConsumeRecord consumeRecord = mapper.readValue(value, ReportWalletConsumeRecord.class);
                        consumeRecord.setMergedRecordCount(1);
                        return consumeRecord;
                    }
                }).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator());

        consumeRecord.keyBy(
                new KeySelector<ReportWalletConsumeRecord, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<String, Long> getKey(ReportWalletConsumeRecord value) throws Exception {
                        return Tuple2.of(value.getConsumeItem(), value.getTenantId());
                    }
                })
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .reduce(new SumField(), new CollectionWindow())
                .addSink(new SinkFunction<List<ReportWalletConsumeRecord>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(List<ReportWalletConsumeRecord> reportPumps, Context context) throws Exception {
                        WalletConsumeRealtimeHandler.invoke(reportPumps);
                    }
                });
        env.execute(WalletConsumeRealtimeHandler.class.getName());
    }

    private static class CollectionWindow extends ProcessWindowFunction<ReportWalletConsumeRecord,
            List<ReportWalletConsumeRecord>,
            Tuple2<String, Long>,
            TimeWindow> {
        public void process(Tuple2<String, Long> key,
                            Context context,
                            Iterable<ReportWalletConsumeRecord> minReadings,
                            Collector<List<ReportWalletConsumeRecord>> out) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<ReportWalletConsumeRecord> employees = Lists.newArrayList(minReadings);
            if (employees.size() > 0) {
                out.collect(employees);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class SumField implements ReduceFunction<ReportWalletConsumeRecord> {
        public ReportWalletConsumeRecord reduce(ReportWalletConsumeRecord d1, ReportWalletConsumeRecord d2) {
            Integer merged1 = d1.getMergedRecordCount() == null ? 1 : d1.getMergedRecordCount();
            Integer merged2 = d2.getMergedRecordCount() == null ? 1 : d2.getMergedRecordCount();
            d1.setMergedRecordCount(merged1 + merged2);
            d1.setConsumeNum(d1.getConsumeNum() + d2.getConsumeNum());
            return d1;
        }
    }

    public static void invoke(List<ReportWalletConsumeRecord> records) {
        WalletConsumeService service = FlinkUtil.InitRetrofit().create(WalletConsumeService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.saveRecords(records);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

and now I found the Flink task only receive at least 2 records to trigger sink, is the reduce action need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two records to trigger the [window](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/windows.html). Flink only knows when to close a window (and fire subsequent calculation) when it receives a watermark that is larger than the configured value of the end of the window.

In your case, you use `BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator`, which updates the watermark according to the incoming records. So it generates a second watermark only after having seen the second record.

You can use a different watermark generator. In the troubleshooting training there is a watermark generator that also [generates watermarks on timeout](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-troubleshooting/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/troubleshoot/TroubledStreamingJobSolution2.java#L129-L187).